# Java Comparing 2 chars and adding them to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, char

The idea is that the user inputs a char. The char is then matched against the ArrayList of chars and if the char is already on there then it will return a print statement, but if it's not on there , then it will be added to the ArrayList. Here is my bit of code:

```
                System.out.println("Enter Your guess: ");
                char c1 = input.next().charAt(0);


                for(Character c: characters){
                    if(c.equals(c1)){
                        System.out.println("Cant do that");
                    }
                    else{
                        characters.add(c1);
                    }
```

I've tried debugging through it and what seems to happen is that it takes in the value of c1 but then it fails and it doesn't do anything within the if statement. So I'm having difficulty comparing the two chars. Any help here would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
          ArrayList testList = new ArrayList();
              System.out.println("Enter Your guess: ");
            char c1 = input.next().charAt(0);
             testList.add(c1)
               if(false==testList.contains(c1))
                { 
                    System.out.println("Cant do that");
                }
                else
                {
                    testList.add(c1);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 String temp = Character.toString(c);
 String temp1 = Character.toString(c1);
 if(temp.equals(temp1)){

 }
```

Comment: Why you want to do that? There is a perfectly fine `equals` method in `Character` class

Comment: Hmm this comes up with 'Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type char'

Comment: @raj What's the problem with `c.equals(c1)`? This is perfectly fine.

Comment: Cannot invoke equals(char) on the primitive type char @ZouZou

Comment: @raj No that's not possible, because `c` is a `Character` so `c1` is boxed to `Character`. Try `Character c = 'd'; char c1 = 'd'; System.out.println(c.equals(c1));`

Comment: ya that is fine itll work if u use Charactor c='';  Charactor c2='';

Comment: @raj Did you try to run the snippet of code I commented? See http://ideone.com/zinBHy.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try

```
if (characters.contains(c)) {
  // cannot add...
} else {
  // can add.
}
```

BTW if characters is a Set then it will only store unique values.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>(0);

    list.add('a');
    list.add('b');
    list.add('c');
    list.add('d');
    list.add('e');

    char c = 'e';

    if (list.contains(c)) {
        System.out.println(c + "already in list");
    } else {
        list.add(c);
    }

    System.out.println(list.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have a `ConcurrentModificationException` running this code because you're trying to modify the list while iterating it.

Even if this error was not a problem, you approach won't work because you only check if the first char is equals to the one you inputted.

The best way to perform your task is to use a `Set`, as it doesn't allow duplicated elements.

```
Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('a','b','c'));

...

System.out.println("Enter Your guess: ");
char c1 = input.next().charAt(0);
if(set.contains(c1)){
    System.out.println("char already in the set");
} else {
  set.add(c1);
}
```

Alternatively you could simply do

```
System.out.println("Enter Your guess: ");
char c1 = input.next().charAt(0);
boolean added = set.add(c1);
if(!added){
    System.out.println("char already in the set");
}
```

Since `add` returns false and leaving the set inchanged if the element was already present in it.